# Board: EK_TM4C123GXL error in any new progect in Code Composer Studio Version: 11.1.0.00011

Tags: c, ide, embedded, code-composer

What am I doing wrong? The new EK_TM4C123GXL board does not work. The Hello World project builds fine, but when flashing or debugging this project, an error occurs:

```
CORTEX_M4_0: GEL Output: 
Memory Map Initialization Complete
CORTEX_M4_0: Loader: One or more sections of your program falls into a memory region that is not writable.  These regions will not actually be written to the target.  Check your linker configuration and/or memory map.
CORTEX_M4_0: Trouble Reading Memory Block at 0x0 on Page 0 of Length 0x4: Received malformed response packet (expected 0xc4, received 0xf7)
CORTEX_M4_0: File Loader: Verification failed: Target failed to read 0x00000000
CORTEX_M4_0: GEL: File: D:\UTAustinX\t01\hello_EK_TM4C123GXL_TI\Debug\hello_EK_TM4C123GXL_TI.out: Load failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved. Reinstalled all software and read this instruction: https://software-dl.ti.com/ccs/esd/documents/users_guide/ccs_getting-started.html